# How to copy files from Docker container to bind mount directory on docker run?

Tags: docker, persistent-storage, docker-volume

In my Dockerfile, I copy a config file over like so:

```
VOLUME ["/root/.litecoin"]

WORKDIR $HOME/.litecoin
COPY litecoin.conf .
```

I'm able to start the docker container with the config file if I use a named or unanamed volume:

```
docker run -d --name litecoind -v litecoin-blockchain:/root/.litecoin -t test
```

or

```
docker run -d --name litecoind -v /root/.litecoin -t test
```

However, if I try with a bind mount (empty directory), it overwrites the contents of `/root/.litecoin` and I lose my config. E.g:

```
docker run --name litecoind -v /mnt/LV_LTC:/root/.litecoin -t test
```

What is the best non-hacky way to get config files copied from the host to the container using bind mounts? It's annoying that my self-contained Docker app is breaking because I need to use bind mounts (block storage).

Comment: When you bind mount a folder on the host to a location in the container, any files in that location within the container are effectively masked. Can you configure your litecoin app to use the config from a different location within the container? Or alternately can it take its data (I'm assuming you are providing it some data from the host in the bind-mount location ) from a different location than the config?

Comment: thanks, that;s what I ended up having to do.